# Using `==` to compare Strings

Tags: java, string

```
String s5="Ram";
String s6="Ram";

System.out.println("  s5==s6  is " + s5==s6);  // false
System.out.println(s5==s6);  // true
```

Why the first line is `false` and the second line is `true` always?

Comment: Just wanted to say, you should use .equals() to compare string values. Because == will always be false. I don't know why it is true in your 5th line.

Comment: @Thilo - you *didn't* have to reopen the question, however briefly it was.  You could've added the dupe to the list.

Comment: @Thilo:  ...then you could have *removed* those dupes from the list.  Again, doesn't necessitate reopening the question.

Comment: @Thilo:  Now - the dupe you linked half-answered the question.  It explained precedence, but not about string interning.  The dupes I had put in there explained what interning was and how it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Because `+` has a higher precedence than `==`,

```
" s5==s6 is "+s5==s6
```

evaluates as

```
" s5==s6 is Ram"=="Ram"
```

which is obviously false. You could have avoided this particular problem by using parentheses:

```
" s5==s6 is "+(s5==s6)
```

Meanwhile,

```
s5==s6
```

evaluates as

```
"Ram"=="Ram"
```

which is true *only because* of automatic interning of string literals in Java. If one of those strings was evaluated rather than a literal, it would be false, as `==` compares object identity, and two different String objects would be evaluated as different even if they had the same content. Compare

```
String s5 = new String("Ram");
String s6 = new String("Ram");
System.out.println(s5==s6); //false
```

Use `.equals` for meaningful comparison of string contents:

```
System.out.println(s5.equals(s6)); //true
```